# How is the timeout for a wrong firmware password determined?

Tags: mac, password, firmware-password

I noticed that when you set a firmware password on your Mac and you enter it incorrectly, the timeout before you can enter a new password keeps increasing with every wrong attempt.

I was wondering: How does a Mac determine the timeout for a wrong firmware password? Would it allow unlimited tries?